# Bootstrap table-striped is missing in visual studio intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2012, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap v3.3.2 (<del>v3.0.1</del>, thx [cvrebert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3342739/cvrebert)), all other table related CSS are present, only table-striped is missing.

[image]

here is bootstrap in head,

```
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

this happens to both my work & home PC, any idea?

Comment: Why are you using such a relatively old version of Bootstrap? Current version is 3.3.2.

Comment: @cvrebert, thx. updated to 3.3.2. same issue.